# Realm: 'Cannot set a default configuration after using per-path configuration methods.' Swift 2

Tags: database, swift, swift2, realm

So I am trying to set a default realm for each user that logs in, and according to realm docs, this can be done by appending a userId after documents and creating a new realm there and setting it as default for each user.

I have a function that performs the code below each time a user logs in, in order to give that user's specific data.

The error I receive though is

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot set a default configuration after using per-path configuration methods.'

However, this appears to be the correct methodology, according to the docs here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-configuration

Here is the Realm docs code:

```
func setDefaultRealmForUser(username: String) {
var config = Realm.Configuration()

// Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
 config.path = config.path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent()
                       .stringByAppendingPathComponent(username)
                       .stringByAppendingPathExtension("realm")

  // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
 }
```

Here is my code (the stringBy... methods were removed in swift 2, so I changed it to use NSURL. However, Realm still reads the path as a String).

```
    var config = Realm.Configuration()
    let realm = try! Realm()
    // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
    var url = NSURL()
    url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: config.path!)
    if let url2 = url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent {
        let url3 = url2.URLByAppendingPathComponent(userId)
        let url4 = url3.URLByAppendingPathExtension("realm")
        config.path = String(url4)
                // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
        if let newPath = config.path {
         Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path = newPath  //fails here

             print("Successfully changed default realm to \(config.path)")
            return
        }
        print("\n\n\n-------ERRORmid setting default realm to \(config.path)----\n\n\n")
        return
    }
    print("\n\n\n-------ERRORlast setting default realm to \(config.path)----\n\n\n")
    return
```

I tried both:

```
   Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path = newPath
```

and

```
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Thank you SO much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're calling one of the following deprecated functions:

```
setSchemaVersion(_:atPath:migrationBlock:)
// or
Realm.setEncryptionKey(_:forPath:)
```

along side your `Realm.Configuration` usage. These methods are incompatible with `Realm.Configuration` so you should move entirely to `Realm.Configuration` to avoid these issues.

These deprecated methods will be removed completely in the next major release of Realm Objective-C and Realm Swift.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However, I am still having trouble creating a new realm at the path. The app fails with "No such file or directory found" when I try! let realm = Realm(). Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like the path you've specified for `Realm.Configuration` isn't valid. What's the path?